# CodeIgniter Transfer Controller's HTML Tags/Fields to View - MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Good day! Lately, it's been a problem for me that my **HTML inputs/divs** are being put to Controller. I'm looking for a solution how can I transfer my fields / inputs to the view so that I'll just call them to the view to controller. and so I can use my code easily. thank you

here is my **Controller** - As you can see there are still `divs` there, so I just want to put them to controller.

```
 function fetch()
  {
      $output = '';
      $query = '';
      $this->load->model('level_model');
      if($this->input->post('query'))
      {
       $query = $this->input->post('query');
      }
      $data = $this->level_model->fetch_data($query);
      $output .= '
       <div class="table-responsive">
         <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <tr>
           <th>Courses Year</th>
       </tr>
      ';
      if($data->num_rows() > 0)
      {
       foreach($data->result() as $row)
       {
        $output .= '
          <tr>
           <td>'.$row->course_year.'</td>
          </tr>
        ';
       }
      }
      else
      {
       $output .= '<tr>
           <td colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
          </tr>';
      }
      $output .= '</table>';
      echo $output;
  }
```

and my **View**

```
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" class="form-control">

<div id="result"></div>
```

**Ajax:**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>levels/fetch",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#search_text').change(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
});
</script>

<script>
```

Comment: you can place your html inside ajax/js to clean your controller

Comment: @YXN - good day! can you please show me your pattern? is it okay to provide a code? sorry im still new in coding here. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use view files for HTML contents.

Use something like this

```
$htmlcontent = $this->load->view('viewfile', $data, true);
echo $htmlcontent;
exit();
```

Comment: how can I do it with the whole process? im kinda new to this mvc pattern thanks

Comment: Pass the $data vaiable to view. Do the same thing in your view file thats all.

Comment: so how's the `<div class="result"></div>` where should I put it the? shall I remove it?

Comment: Write the for loop in view file instead of controller.

Comment: Keep <div class="result"></div> same as now.

Comment: sarath s rajendran - by creating a table? inside the table?